# Unable to SSH into EMR Cluster

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I use airflow to submit multiple hourly spark jobs to an EMR. In one hour I can have upwards to 30 spark submits.

The EMR is 1 master node and 4 core nodes all c4.4xlarge.

My spark submits use master yarn and deploy-mode client.

Every hour multiple airflow dags will ssh into the EMR and spark-submit their jobs. Most of the jobs are small and finishes within a few minutes, except for a few that take 10-15 mins.

I have been hitting a reoccurring error logged by airflow and once one task receives it, it waterfalls down to the rest of them:

`airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: SSH operator error: No existing session`

This means airflow was unable to ssh into the cluster. I even tried to ssh through my computer and it just hangs. Is it possible there are too many spark tasks running? I wouldn't think so because my cluster is pretty big for the jobs I have to run.

Comment: Its definitely not related to multiple Spark tasks. This may be related to max number of SSH connection allowed or some configuration with SSH. Are you using multiple SSH keys to do ssh? Another suggestion is, you can use steps to submit spark jobs which doesn't require SSH.

Comment: I am using 1 SSH key, and i checked the ssh configs. we do not have any max number. I also tried ssh with 40+ connections to a cloned EMR, no issue.

Comment: do u use livy to submit jobs ? if yes then every spark submit spins a local JVM with heap approx 1GB till the yarn scheduler takes the job as submitted. HOwever the defautl EMR configuration doesnt kill the local JVM till the complete spark job complete. If u submit too many spark jobs ur physical memory gets exhosted. -- this can be a reason for erratic behavior.